# Bug? Colored frame in mcode package

Tags: listings, matlab

While using [mcode.sty](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package), I recognized that at linebreaks with long comments parts of the surrounding frame got colored green or were even left white at using mathematical formulas, e.g. in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

% something NOT relevant to the usage of the package.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{18pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item The following demo block shows the problems:
\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:3
    if i >= 5                    % literate programming replacement
        disp('cool');           % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§
    end
    really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How can uniformly black colored frames be achieved?

Comment: I have removed my previous comment, I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: You forgot to include a list-environment (e.g. `itemize`) in your code. The problem only seems to occur in a list, if you remove the `\item` from your code everything works fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thank you for your comment - that environment enabled me to see the bug (because of the smaller textwidth)!

Comment: I hope now people can see the remaining problem/conflict of the frame with math code inside the `lstlisting`-environment.

Comment: For information, this isn't a problem specific to the `mcode` package, but also occurs with the `listings` package (which `mcode` is built on).

Comment: You might want to use the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2):

The first problem can be solved (I think it is a bug in the package mcode.sty) quite simply by adding a few lines of code just after including `\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}`:

```
\lstset{
    rulecolor=\color{black}
}
```

The problem at using mathematical formulas still remains.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer, so that it be removed from the pile of "unanswered" questions.